# Using Linux as guest on vmware and sharing connection with windows vista

Tags: windows, internet, vmware, connection

I've been trying for weeks with vmwware player, now d/l vmwware work station 7, I have a laptop with one built in modem and a usb modem I bought, It works great switching it over from host to use in ubuntu to connect to the net.

When I use that modem from the host to connect online I have no trouble getting ubuntu to share the internet connection, but tried with NAT bridge host and all to get it to work from ubuntu to share the internet connection to windows vista, the host, I know it should work if it works the other way around, I tried setting up my `wlan0` `eht0` and `eth1` to the correct IP can get both systems to notice each other by name and ip, but cant get them to share the connection from guest to host.

I've tried iptables and all as well, Can someone please help me out with this? I am sure It is something I'm over looking, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You said "but tried with NAT bridge". That doesn't make sense. You can either choose NAT or bridged. NAT means that the guest can access the network, but other computers (including the host) on the network don't see the guest VM. If you use bridged, it means that the guest gets it's own IP on the network, and that other computers can access it via the IP.

Sounds like you should be using bridged for what you want to do.

You'll then need to set up the guest operating system as a router, to do NAT translation from the virtual network card to forward packets to the modem.

Then you'll change the host operation system's network settings to use the guest as a router. (You could also run DHCP on the guest to do this if you want to, but probably not worth the bother in this case).

The reason it just worked when you were using the modem on the guest, is that the NAT settings in Vmware automatically handle the NAT translation, and also configure the guest systems network settings via DHCP to use the host as a router. You don't get that with bridged.

Comment: I was referring to using Nat/Bridge & Host to try and get the connection from the guest to share it to the host, Sorry for confusing you.I wouldn't even know how to go about, making my guest into a router,the problem is,I don't have access to the main router,Many of us sharing off of it. Now when I use windows vista the host, with NAT I can share the internet connection to the guest, Ubuntu, So is there away from me to setup a NAT from the guest to share internet connection to the host? All wireless mind you, How do I go about setting up vm guest as a router to share the connection with host?